# Как отключить/включить объект по индексу массива?

Tags: unity3d

Как отключить из GameObject[] отключить 1,2,4 объекты?Через foreach задействует все объекты что есть в массиве.

Comment: сразу несколько. GameObject[2].SetActive(true/false) Знаю, но хочется как нибудь без тонны однотипного кода с разными индексами

Comment: Ну если вам GameObject[i].SetActive(true/false) не подходит, то делайте GameObject[i].transform.SetParent(parent.Transform); parent.SetActive(false); :)

Comment: это еще больше затронет cpu+ такой же большой код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создаём массив, которым будем управлять.

```
GameObject[] gameObjects = new GameObject[10];
```

// создаём список элементов, которых нужно отключить

```
  HashSet<int> set = new HashSet<int>();
    set.Add(1);
    set.Add(2);
    set.Add(4);
    for (int i = 0; i < gameObjects.Length; i++)
    {
       // если текущий номер нам подходит отключает объект
        if (set.Contains(i))
            gameObjects[i].SetActive(false);
    }
```

Comment: интересно.спасибо

Comment: @Des если ответ оказался полезным, отметь как правильный